# Descendents of a table row

Tags: jquery

I have a table with several rows containing several cells of form inputs (see HTML snippet below). I have a function that removes and individual rows and I'm trying to reindex all of those that remain by iterating over each row (to get the new row index) and, within that, iterating over each input (`$('td input', $row).each( ... )`) and updating the `name` and `id` attributes.  What I'm finding is that the inputs in the first cell get reindexed, but not the cost input in the second cell.

Any idea what I'm missing that's keeping that second cell from getting updated?

Thanks.

HTML Snippet:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" name="data[Ticket][0][id]" value="" id="Ticket0Id">       
      <input type="hidden" name="data[Ticket][0][date_id]" value="" id="Ticket0DateId">            
      <input name="data[Ticket][0][name]" type="text" maxlength="45" value="" id="Ticket0Name">          
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="data[Ticket][0][cost]" type="text" value="" id="Ticket0Cost">         
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" name="data[Ticket][1][id]" value="" id="Ticket1Id">            
      <input type="hidden" name="data[Ticket][1][date_id]" value="" id="Ticket1DateId">            
      <input name="data[Ticket][1][name]" type="text" maxlength="45" value="" id="Ticket1Name">          
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="data[Ticket][1][cost]" type="text" value="" id="Ticket1Cost">          
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

By popular demand, here's the jQuery snippet that attempts to do the reindexing:

```
// $tbody references the <tbody> element in the snippet above
$('tr', $tbody).each( function( i, row ) {
  var $row = $(row);

  $('td input', $row).each( function( j, input ) {
    $(input).attr( 'id', $(this).attr( 'id' ).replace( /\d+/g, i ) )
    $(input).attr( 'name', $(this).attr( 'name' ).replace( /\d+/g, i ) );
  })
});
```

Comment: can your provide your jQuery code?

Comment: can you post your js code and/or a working example on jsfiddle?

Comment: $('td input', $row).each( ... )) -- what's $row?

Comment: Posted. Meant to do that in the first place.

Comment: Seems to work fine to me.  http://jsfiddle.net/hVhXE/

Comment: @mblase75 Hmmm. Seems to work for me too. Guess I need to figure out what's different. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I may have been relying too heavily on Safari's web inspector to determine whether the attributes were being reindexed. It seems that if you have an element expanded, changes to that element are not reflected when they happen. Next time, I'll verify with jsfiddle first (or at least second). Lesson learned.

This one's on me. Sorry, folks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead as your selector:

```
$tr.find('input').each(function(j, input) { });
```